# How can I get max and min numeric value with in the search in algolia

Tags: search, algolia

I am trying to limit my date range filter to be with in the max and min date value to the result ( the whole result not just the first page ) is there a way algolia returns the min and max of that value with in the returned data
Note: its a numeric attribute not a facet

Comment: Can you tell me more about which library of Algolia you're using, InstantSearch, Autocomplete, Helper ...

Comment: actually we are using the helper to code the engine ourselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the facets you defined contains numerical values, the API response will contain a `facets_stats` key. It's an object with one key per facet, and each of those keys contains the following informations: `min`, `max`, `avg` and `sum`.

[image]

You can find more informations about the API response format [in the doc](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/search/#fields).

The JS Helper actually has a [getFacetStats](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#SearchResults#getFacetStats) method to get that data.

Note that those values are dynamic, and relative to the others filters currently applied (ie. they are the min and max values of the items that *currently match your query*). If you want the absolute min and max of all the items in your index, you will have to do first an empty query (no filters, no keyword) and save those min/max somewhere.

You have to add you attribute to the `attributesForFacetting` for this to work.

Comment: Thats right, I just didnt want to add the numeric attribute as facet but seems like thats the only way to get the data

Thanks

Comment: Addition, when adding attributesForFacetting, for numeric attribute, have to add it as "searchable" . Did't work for me when I add it as filterOnly.